# Scala Type Equivalence Checking on Singleton Types

Tags: scala, typechecking, singleton-type

I have a function to witness type equivalence:

```
def typeEq[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B) = println("happy")
typeEq: [A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B)Unit
```

It fails to check the following two different singleton types:

```
class X
val a = new X; val b = new X
val aa:a.type = a; val bb:b.type = b
typeEq(aa, bb)
```

However, if I write this way, the compiler works fine:

```
class X
val a = new X; val b = new X
type atype=a.type; type btype=b.type
val aa:atype = a; val bb:btype = b
typeEq(aa, bb)

<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that atype =:= btype.
   typeEq(aa, bb)
         ^
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please replace your photos of code with the actual code. It's off-topic until you do.

Comment: What do you mean by *two different singleton types*?  `a` and `b` both have type `X`. So why do you expect an error from your function?